# Unity NavMesh obstacle uncarve?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

Is there a way to undo all the changes that navmesh obstacle does and reset my NavMesh to its original baked form (using scripts while the player is playing)?

Thanks

Comment: a sophisticated question.

Comment: i dont really get the question since unity shows this very behavior on my end?